# Developing an Asp.net MVC website : which requirements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm about to develop an ASP.NET Mvc website for a startup. I've never done this before, so i have few architecture/infrastructure asks.

1/ Is it reasonable to develop the website in Asp.NET Core MVC ? I've read several times that the technology may not be mature for the next 1-2 years.

2/ In a first time, i'll have a low budget. Knowing this, would it be possible to use TFS ? IIS ? Sql Server ? If it is too expansive, which are the alternatives ?

3/ Should i host the website using Microsoft Azure ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an advice forum. This question is too broad and is based too much on opinion. Break this question down into multiple questions and ask them separately.

Comment: @Alex this question is a _very_ poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat, agree, but SE is better for this kind of questions anyway

Comment: @Alex no it isn't, have you read meta guidance referred in prior comment?

Comment: @gnat, TL to read, will look later. But I understand that questions related to architecture and structure of your application are better for SE than SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can share my own experience on this matter. The definite answer is **yes**.

- 1. Yes, it is reasonable. You have mentioned it would be a startup, so you are fortunate to try *latest* technologies. Microsoft has actually **released** .NET Core and they are offering **long term support** for the release. Microsoft takes LTS seriously. I am using ASP Core from early beta and although there were some problems back then, it is quite stable now.
- 2. TFS, IIS and SQL Server are different products for different purposes. Thankfully, you do not have to stick with Microsoft stack entirely. I am using PostgresSQL (with Entity Framework), Kestrel + NGINX on Linux (Ubuntu 16) and Git (gitlab). All of them are stable, open source and no worse than Microsoft solutions.
- 3. In my personal experience Azure is great but too expensive. That was the main reason I tried moving to .NET Core instead of Windows only - I wanted to host it elsewhere. Given that the ASP Core is released, you have at least two options. You can self host (what I do) get cheap VPS from Google/DigitalOcean/Amazon/..., install ASP Core (or Docker) and be happy. This way is cheap, and you are in full control, but it requires some Linux Administration skills. The other way is to find non-Azure ASP hosting, like SmarterASP (just an example, not ad) and publish your product right from the Visual Studio.

To sum up, **yes** it is reasonable to build your app on ASP Core.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I feel reassured now.

Comment: I don't know why you answered such an opinion-soliciting question. "No" would be another reasonable answer to the use of asp.net core (directly in opposition to your "yes.") And I can't imagine how you came up with Azure being too expensive, since you didn't even back up that assertion (and then proposed other clouds along with docker, which ironically works perfectly on Azure).

Comment: @CasqueOuille - How, exactly, do you feel reassured, because one person told you to use the product you're thinking of using? And then told you not to use Azure? This is nothing but someone's opinion of a bunch of technology choices. And even called Azure "too expensive" yet didn't back it up with anything. I can't imagine why you accepted this as an answer.

Comment: @CasqueOuille - You are welcome! Was glad to share my experience.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - I knew it was opinion-soliticing and I warned in advance that I share my experience. I do not claim that my opinion is right or wrong, it's just mine. If you happen to have different opinion, why don't you share it with us. Downvoting is always easier. For example, I would be very glad to know that Azure stopped being too expensive (I gave $50 for azure and $10 for DigitalOcean for same kind of experience).